# specify font in Python pdfkit

Tags: python, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I'm using python 3.6 with pdfkit 0.6.1 (and it seems wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2) on a Debian Docker image. I tried looking at the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/#usage) & [wkhtmltopdf options](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) but there's no way to specify the font for the whole document. There are only font options for footers & headers.

I tried specifying

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

In a `div` wrapper in my html `<style>` section before html to pdf conversion, but it's not coming up "Times New Roman". Looking into the binary, it seems it's using `DejaVuSerif`.

Is there a way to specify the font for the document being converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I need to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, but first, I need to add `contrib` into my `sources.list`

```
sed -Ei 's/main$/main contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then install the package

```
apt-get -y install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

The closest free font I was able to find was `Liberation Serif` in `ttf-liberation`, which means the html style font had to be changed to:

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, "Liberation Serif", serif;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to customize the font of my entire document passing a CSS stylesheet using `user-style-sheet`. Inside your CSS file, in order to avoid issues with the font structure, I recommend you to convert the font to a base64 format. [base64 reference](https://blog.shaharia.com/use-google-web-fonts-for-wkhtmltopdf-tools-to-convert-html-to-pdf)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(data:font/opentype;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAD00AA4A---[large string ommited]----3MAuAH/hbAEjQA=) format("woff"),
    url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAARAQAABAAQRFNJRwAAAAEAAJUIAAA---[large string ommited]-----wAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA) format("truetype");
}

* {
  font-family: "YourFont" !important;
}
```

You can use a tool like [this](https://transfonter.org/) to transform your font to `base64`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I wasn't able to find any other way to work around this.